# controllers and viewcontrollers in extjs5

Tags: extjs, mvvm, extjs5

I am getting started with ExtJS 5 and MVVM architecture. I would like to know if the application-wide controllers can coexist along side View-specific view controllers applying view-specific within the viewControllers and application common logic in the application-wide controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they can. 4.2-style controllers still work in ExtJS 5, and still have a place in co-ordinating application-wide and cross-view logic, as you say. They just aren't as documented as well - so keep the 4.2 documentation handy.